# Delete other files in Parse Cloud Code

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform, cloud, parse-cloud-code

I added a new javascript file to my cloud code called push_cloud_code.js. As seen in this pic:[image]

I am wondering how to delete this file from my cloud code files. If it is even possible?

And I was also wondering how I can call this function in iOS. Or can you only call functions that are in the main.js file, using this code for example:

```
 [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"push"
                   withParameters:@{}
                            block:^(NSString *result, NSError *error) {
                                if (!error) {
                                    // result is @"push"
                                }
                            }];
```

Thanks a bunch for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately neither running or deleting this file is supported on parse, if you go to the parse.com forums though it seems like they are working on making you able to run these soon.